# Ignore parameters that are null in active record Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I created a simple web form where users can enter some search criteria to look for venues e.g. a price range. When a user clicks "find" I use active record to query the database. This all works very well if all fields are filled in. Problems occur when one or more fields are left open and therefore have a value of null.

How can I work around this in my controller? Should I first check whether a value is null and create a query based on that? I can imagine I end up with many different queries and a lot of code. There must be a quicker way to achieve this?

Controller:

```
def search
   @venues = Venue.where("price >= ? AND price <= ? AND romance = ? AND firstdate = ?", params[:minPrice], params[:maxPrice], params[:romance], params[:firstdate])
end
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You may want to filter out all of the blank parameters that were sent with the request.

Here is a quick and DRY solution for filtering out blank values, triggers only one query of the database, and builds the where clause with Rails' ActiveRecord ORM.

This approach safeguards against SQL-injection, as pointed out by @DanBrooking. Rails 4.0+ provides "strong parameters." You should use the feature.

```
class VenuesController < ActiveRecord::Base

  def search
    # Pass a hash to your query
    @venues = Venue.where(search_params)
  end

  private

    def search_params
      params.
        # Optionally, whitelist your search parameters with permit
        permit(:min_price, :max_price, :romance, :first_date).
        # Delete any passed params that are nil or empty string
        delete_if {|key, value| value.blank? }
    end
end
```

Comment: This is the correct answer and should be the accepted answer. The accepted answer is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to make method in Venue

```
def self.find_by_price(min_price, max_price)
   if min_price && max_price
     where("price between ? and ?", min_price, max_price)
   else
     all
   end
 end

def self.find_by_romance(romance)
   if romance
     where("romance = ?", romance)
   else
     all
   end
 end

def self.find_by_firstdate(firstdate)
   if firstdate
     where("firstdate = ?", firstdate)
   else
     all
   end
 end
```

And use it in your controller 
`Venue
.find_by_price(params[:minPrice], params[:maxPrice])
.find_by_romance(params[:romance])
.find_by_firstdate(params[:firstdate])`

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to this problem, and I think a more elegant one, is using scopes with conditions.
You could do something like

```
class Venue < ActiveRecord::Base   
  scope :romance, ->(genre) { where("romance = ?", genre) if genre.present? } 
end
```

You can then chain those, which would work as an AND if there is no argument present, then it is not part of the chain.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes

Answer (score -1):

Try below code, it will ignore parameters those are not present

```
conditions = []
conditions << "price >= '#{params[:minPrice]}'" if params[:minPrice].present?
conditions << "price <= '#{params[:maxPrice]}'" if params[:maxPrice].present?
conditions << "romance = '#{params[:romance]}'" if params[:romance].present?
conditions << "firstdate = '#{params[:firstdate]}'" if params[:firstdate].present?

@venues = Venue.where(conditions.join(" AND "))
```

Comment: btw isn't this method not vulnerable to sql injection? "price >= #{query}" rather than "price >= ?, query" ?